# cant search the mail by "Search for mail to a recipient" in the sent folder

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, search

I use Outlook 2016 and win10 in my daily work. I met a problem whiling I search the mail with different searching skills. when I search for specific mail by title, Outlook would get the specific and fittable searching outcomes for me(as the picture 1), but when I searching the mail by "Search for mail to a recipient" for targeting the same email(as the picture 2), Outlook could not get this mail for me, is there any bug or misusing for the problem?

picture-1

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbbUj.jpg

picture-2

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJDJJ.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Does this problem only occur in the Sent folder? Please try **To:"nick"** and see if there is any difference.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I have tried, but nothing show on the outcome.